# Magento - Vertical Menu from Top Navigation

Tags: html, css, magento, navigation, megamenu

I am new to Magento and would like to have a navigation menu like the one on this website www.wilko.com

I have searched for days and looked at many menu options that profess to do what I want but don't unless I am missing something.

Am I asking for something that is impossible in Magento. I am surprised there has not been a need for such a menu structure until now? Or is my thinking on navigation all wrong?

Any help or advice gratefully received. I did also search this forum but couldn't find what I was looking for but I could be using the wrong terminology so apologies if this question has come up before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link

https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-category-menu-navigation-in-magento/

It may be some help

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Include all necessary information into your answer to make it self-contained.

Comment: Thanks I have looked at this however this gives me a vertical left or right fixed menu which is not what I was after. The menu in the link I posted is exactly what I am looking for however it seems un-achievable. 
I am not a coder but can tinker happily with existing code or extensions if pointed in the right direction.